# scss function output as keyframe step percentages

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I'm doing complex keyframe animations and my current process is to input the duration of the animation into a spreadsheet that will tell me all the percentages that my time points line up with, then copying those percentages back into my css. This is becoming quite laborious, particularly if I change the duration for any reason, then all the percentages change. I'd like to use a function to simplify this that looks like:

```
@function secPerc($currentTime,$totalTime){
  @return ($currentTime*100)/$totalTime * 100%;
}
```

And trying to use the output:

```
secPerc(0.8/2) {transform: rotate(70deg);}
```

Keeps getting compile errors. Also attempted using a mixin to no avail. Please see [this simplified Codepen](https://codepen.io/Kaijin/pen/vRaWYm) as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to use a function, mixin or variable inside the selector or the attribute name part, you need to tell SASS to parse it as such, by placing it inside a `#{expression}` syntax.

Secondly, even if you do try to compile the function, you'll discover it expects two arguments (because that's how you defined it) and you are only passing one (`0.8/2` simply equals `0.4` => one argument).
Make sure you pass all the required parameters your custom function expects, if you want it to output anything:

```css
@keyframes spin {
  ...
  #{secPerc(0.8, 2)} {
    transform: rotate(70deg);
  }
  ...
}
```

https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/wmxpqB

---

By the way, did you know you can now create complex keyframe animations using a tool (visual timing function editor) in Chrome development console  which allows you to modify any `animation-timing-function` to create `cubic-bezier()` functions, without needing to remember 
(or make much sense of) their values? Just give your element any valid `cubic-bezier()` value and inspect it. Click on the small icon beside its value and you'll get the visual editor for the timing-function. It's pretty cool! Chances are you'll get the animation you want, without needing to do all the math yourself. You'll get the result faster and the end result will be faster, as "natural" as you want it and easier to control and tweak.

Comment: Second point first: yeah that was a typo, I did intend a comma there.

Thank you very much for pointing out the #{expression} syntax! I did have to adjust my function to get it to work: the *100% did not end up getting the animation to run although it did compile. I moved the % symbol outside of the function and voila it's working!